# How to show only section of site in UiWebView?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to show site in UiWebView but I don't need to show all site but only from `<section id="xxx">` to `</section>` with optional `<head>` for CSS styles. I tried to download html code and paste it to UiWebView

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/page"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSString* content2 = string;
NSString* beforeBody = @"<section id=";
NSString* afterBody = @"</section>";

NSString* finalContent = [[beforeBody stringByAppendingString:content2]
                          stringByAppendingString: afterBody];

[_webView loadHTMLString:finalContent baseURL:nil];
```

but it didn't work for me. Any ideas? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Create 2 UIWebViews in your viewController, webView and webView2, implement `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>` in your viewController header.

In viewDidAppear you will load the fullHTMLString from the page you would like to work with into webView2 and afterwards set the delegate for webView2 like so:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *fullHTMLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://python.org"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

    [self.webView2 setHidden:YES];
    [self.webView2 loadHTMLString:fullHTMLString baseURL:nil];
    [self.webView2 setDelegate: self];
}
```

You will have to implement webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method, and in it you call for `[stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString]`, which will retrieve your desired single element based on parameters you give it.

In this example I chose to retrieve it by ElementID, you can use javascript to retrieve it in other ways.

Once you have your desired element to display, you create an HTML string and insert it into it, afterwards you load the full html with the single element into the first webView (webView and not webView2) this is done to prevent an endless loop while calling the delegate method.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    NSString *singleElementString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"mainnav\").innerHTML;"];
    NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<html>%@</html>", singleElementString];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```